# Convert and break a 2 byte integer into 2 different uchars in C++ with endianess compatibility

Tags: c++, byte, endianness

I would like to convert an unsigned int and break it into 2 uchars.

```
For example: 
uint16 current = 23;
uchar a[2];
```

I should have put this in words as, a[0] should hold 3 and a[1] should hold 1
This should be compatible with both big endian and little endian system.

I tried:

```
uint16 final = 23;
uchar a[2];
uint16 *current = (uint16 *)a;
*current = final;
```

But, this has endianness issue

Comment: What do you mean about compatibility? You want the same results or different results for different machines?

Comment: I want the same result across both systems

Comment: Your `uchar` lines don't make sense either. Are those supposed to be binary constants? Why are they '2' and '7'?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You edited the constants, but they still don't make sense. Are you trying to get BCD?  Or did you mean `current = 0x0203`?

Comment: By the way, numbers with preceeding 0 are by default in Octal notation.

Comment: You constants are still not correct.  The number 23 base 10 is 0x17 not 0x23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness is a nonissue:

```
uint16_t a = 23;
uint8_t b[2];
b[0] = a & 0xff;
b[1] = a >> 8;
```

`b[0]` will always be the low-order byte, and `b[1]` the high-order byte.

Comment: i think he wants each byte to contain the next power of 10 value, i.e. B[0] = 3, b[1] = 2

Comment: @James, yeah I'm not sure he knows what he wants, because his question asks one thing, but his code says another... I guess we'll see.